# Superscript ordinals for street labels in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, arcade

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0. I have a Streets feature class that includes the ordinal for numeric streets in the street name field. For example, for "13th Street", the name field is "13th" instead of "13". I want to label these numbered streets with the ordinal in superscript. So instead of 13TH or 13th, I want 13th. Like this:
[image]

Is there a way to make these ordinals superscript in an Arcade labeling expression? I am aware of the Arcade superscript labeling syntax `'<SUP>'+$feature.ST_NAME+'</SUP>'` and that would work great if the ordinals were pulled into a separate field.  Am I missing something obvious?

The street name field also includes non-numerical street names like Main, Hwy 160, and CR 240.

Comment: Looking to use the abbreviate dictionary? return Replace($feature.name, "Street-", "ST-") https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/text/abbreviate-and-truncate-labels.htm (Maplex Labeling enabled).

Answer (score -1):

With the help of the oh-so-handy [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat), I used the following Python code to parse ordinals to a new field.

```
import re

def parse_ordinal(street_name):
    # Use a regular expression to search for ordinal patterns in the street name
    match = re.search(r'\b(\d+)(st|nd|rd|th)\b', street_name)
    if match:
        # Return the ordinal found in the street name
        return match.group(1) + match.group(2)
    else:
        # Return an empty string if no ordinal is found
        return ''

# Example usage
street_name = "123rd street"
print(parse_ordinal(street_name)) # Output: "123rd"
```

If you want to just return the ordinal, delete the `match.group(1) +`  from the code. From there, you can work with label classes to create "Numbered" and "Named" street classes based on the presence of an ordinal in the parse_ordinal result.

[image]